# How to use the subprocess Popen.communicate() method?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to get the standard output of a bash command as a string in Python. Following [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) documentation, I've tried:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "hello"])
stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()

print stdoutdata
```

Running this script yields the following output:

```
hello
None
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

So although the output is getting printed by Python, the `stdoutdata` variable is `None`, and not `"hello"` as I would like. How can I make it so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not providing any stdout to the Popen constructor, the default functionality simply writes the output to parent's stdout handle. Hence you're seeing it being printed in your shell.

Quoting from [`Popen`'s docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> With the default settings of `None`, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.

---

To populate stdout in resulting tuple use `subprocess.PIPE` as stdout.

Quoting from [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> To get anything other than `None` in the result tuple, you need to give
>   `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "hello"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.communicate()
('hello\n', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `stdout`, `stderr` flags to `Popen` constructor.
Per default they are set to `None`, resulting in `Popen` is not capturing them.

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "hello"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = cmd.communicate()
# retCode = cmd.returncode
# retCode != 0, indicates an error occured in execution.
print (out)
>>> b'hello\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) method is what I need:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello"])
```

The `output` is now `'hello\n'` (including a newline character) as I would expect.