# Powershell: Getting GPS Coordinates in Windows 10 - Using Windows Location API?

Tags: powershell, geolocation, gps, windows-10, windows-locationapi

I'm looking for a way to gather internal GPS data from a powershell script using Windows Location API, as the Windows Location Platform is no longer able to satisfy the need. Previously, there was a com object to use.

Is there a way for this to be accomplished in Windows 10?

Comment: more solutions [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119078/err-where-am-i?newreg=983b00097ef141c6b1fbb7f29b357886#answer-119091).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An example of using the `System.Device.Location` method, this should be what you're looking for.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Device #Required to access System.Device.Location namespace
$GeoWatcher = New-Object System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher #Create the required object
$GeoWatcher.Start() #Begin resolving current locaton

while (($GeoWatcher.Status -ne 'Ready') -and ($GeoWatcher.Permission -ne 'Denied')) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 #Wait for discovery.
}  

if ($GeoWatcher.Permission -eq 'Denied'){
    Write-Error 'Access Denied for Location Information'
} else {
    $GeoWatcher.Position.Location | Select Latitude,Longitude #Select the relevent results.
}
```

Comment: Tried it. It works (no "Access Denied.."). But it gives a totally wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure location is set on. Ohterwise it outputs 'Access Denied for Location Information'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer, which uses `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher`, throws   throws **Access Denied for Location Information**, then Windows ability to provide location to apps is probably disabled.  To turn this on, in Windows go to:

**Start** > **Settings** > **Privacy** > **Location**.

Turn on **Allow access to location on this device**.

Turn on **Allow apps to access your location**.